# Mongodb obter registros com prioridade

Tags: mongodb

Tenho 3 `collections` no MongoDB sendo duas listas contendo apenas um identificador único e na `collection` restante o identificador único, nome e sobrenome. O que preciso fazer é uma consulta que seja ordenada por prioridade: quem está na `lista1` vem primeiro, depois quem está na `lista2` e por último o que não consta apenas no documento de 3 campos. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

UPDATE: juntar tudo na mesma collection não é uma opção, e em SQL é feito dessa forma https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/do7HsPcFxvohS7TBth7Kmz/1

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao site! Tenta adicionar exemplos dos documentos na sua pergunta, fica mais fácil de entender o que você precisa. Uma dúvida que me ocorreu aqui: qual a necessidade de manter esses dados em três collections separadas?

Comment: Então Jorge, eu sou bem iniciante no mongo vou chamar de lista 1 a de maior prioridade a lista 2 segunda maior prioridade é a última o listão, a lista 1 e 2 tem apenas um field, que é vamos supor o CPF, já a lista 3 tem CPF, nome e sobrenome, aí quero pesquisar o nome Astolfo, vai me retornar todas as ocorrências de Astolfo, só que desejo que se algum Astolfo tiver seu CPF na lista 1 ele apareça primeiro, assim por diante

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo as especificações que você deu no comentário, eu adicionaria todas as informações em uma collection só.

Me parece que você tem três listas como entrada de dados. Você poderia colocar a prioridade como um campo dentro do documento:

```
{
   "cpf" : 12345678900,
   "nome" : "Astolfo"
   "prioridade" : 1
},
{
   "cpf" : 98765432100,
   "nome" : "João"
   "prioridade" : 2
}
```

Considerei que o Astolfo estava na lista 1 e o João na lista 2. Você poderia fazer índices com os campos que precisa pesquisar, por CPF por exemplo, e pelo campo de prioridade. Dessa maneira você precisa manter, consultar e atualizar somente uma collection. No final é só ordenar a consulta pela prioridade:

```
      db.pessoas.find({"cpf":12345678900},{"prioridade":1})
```

Se houverem dois documentos com o mesmo CPF na collection eles vão aparecer na ordem da prioridade.

Comment: Infelizmente juntar todos em uma única collection não é uma opção :( em SQL seria feito desse jeito https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/do7HsPcFxvohS7TBth7Kmz/1

Comment: Porquê não é uma opção juntar em uma collection? Você até tem um operador para fazer left join no mongo, fazer isso nesse caso seria perverter o banco para a tua necessidade. Você deveria escolher o banco de acordo com a necessidade.

Comment: Na verdade é uma opção, desde que eu consiga fazer esse Merge, por que tô importando todas essas informações de 3 arquivos csv

Comment: No mongo não existe problema algum de você ter documentos com campos diferentes. Usando o mongo, creio que a melhor saída é importar em uma collection só.